# How can I tell when a web page resource is cached?

Tags: javascript, browser, caching

Is there a way in JavaScript for me to tell whether a resource is already in the browser cache?

We're instrumenting a fraction of our client-side page views so that we can get better data on how quickly pages are loading for our users. The first time users arrive on our site, a number of resources (JS, CSS, images) are cached by the browser, so their initial pageview is going to be slower than subsequent ones.

Right now, that data is mixed together, so it's hard to tell an initial page load from a subsequent pageview that's slow for some other reason. I'd love a cross-browser way to check to see whether the cache is already primed, so that I can segregate the two sorts of pageview and analyze them separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a JavaScript API for checking if a resource is cached. I think the best you can do is check how long it took to load the resources, and bucket the ones with shorter load times together.

At the top of the page:

```
<script>var startPageLoad = new Date().getTime();</script>
```

On each resource:

```
<img src="foo.gif" onload="var fooLoadTime = startPageLoad - new Date().getTime()">
<script src="bar.js" onload="var barLoadTime = startPageLoad - new Date().getTime()">
```

When reporting load times:

```
var fooProbablyCached = fooLoadTime < 200; // Took < 200ms to load foo.gif
var barProbablyCached = barLoadTime < 200; // Took < 200ms to load bar.gif
```

You may need to use onreadystatechange events instead of onload in IE.

Comment: Thanks, Annie. That makes perfect sense. Some browsers are weird when you mix script blocks and loading external resources, so this may impact parallel downloads; I'll try it and see.

Comment: Hi William, looking at browserscope, it looks like what you want to watch out for is a stylesheet immediately followed by an inline script: http://www.browserscope.org/?v=top&category=network (The other parallel download issues all apply to external scripts).

Comment: My server count up a variable and send it with the Content-MD5 header.
The client script will check if the Content-MD5 header exists and is greater than before. If so the response is not cached. I do something like that for security reason.

Comment: Drawback: you have to wait for the ressource to be loaded before being able to say wether it was cached or not...

Answer (score 7):

You should use [TransferSize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceResourceTiming/transferSize):

```
window.performance.getEntriesByName("https://[resource-name].js")[0].transferSize
```

To verify it, you can run the above line on Chrome...

- If the browser has caching enabled and your resource was previously loaded with proper `cache-control` header, `transferSize` should be 0.
- If you disable caching (Network tab -> Disable cache) and reload, `transferSize` should be > 0.

Comment: Sadly safari doesn't support `.transferSize` yet :(

Answer (score -1):

You need a plug-in to do this. [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) can tell you on the "NET" tab, once you install it (for Firefox). JavaScript itself cannot see the browser's HTTP traffic.

Comment: As I mention in the question, I'm doing client-side instrumentation on real pageviews. It is unlikely that I will get a lot of our users to install Firebug, especially the ones who don't use Firefox.

Comment: Not liking the truth is no reason for a down-vote. Thanks. :(

Comment: Your answer could be fine on a different question, but it's unhelpful here. Making sure the most helpful answer is at the top of the page seems a reasonable use of up- and down-voting to me.