# Detect if chrome is loading a cached page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, express, browser-cache

This is one of those, "I need a workaround so as not to have to endure 1000 years of bickering from users, once the project launches" type questions:

I have a situation where I need to have my site reload any time someone launches Chrome without closing the tab last time they closed the browser. We are rebuilding an ancient site in a modern, MEAN stack environment, and I just **know** I will get complaints on this when it launches.

In other words **(danger: psuedocode) -**

```
if client closed chrome with site open
  reauthenticate user
  redirect to home page
```

I can accomplish the last two bits through an express route and passport auth, but how do I detect if the client is loading a cached page from their end?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260043/how-can-i-use-javascript-to-detect-if-i-am-on-a-cached-page

Comment: Doesnt the same happen when you leave the tab and go back to it after some time?

Comment: To clarify, I'm looking to reload the page ANY time it's opened from the client cache, as loading a cached page causes some 500 errors with our setup

Comment: Is it possible to simply store some sort of js variable that is only set true after an actual login, or does Chrome keep that stored on close as well?

Comment: @CriticalError In the authentication portion, hmm.....it's worth a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to simply store some sort of js variable that is only
>   set true after an actual login, or does Chrome keep that stored on
>   close as well?

A simple example to go along with my comment:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>

        function DoMagic() {
            document.getElementById( "magic" ).innerHTML = "<h1>Hello World!</h1>";
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="magic">Waiting for magic</div>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Do Magic" onclick="DoMagic();" />

</body>
</html>
```

- Open this in Chrome the div reads "Waiting for magic".
- Click "Do Magic" div reads "Hello World".
- Close Chrome by clicking X ( not the page, the browser ).
- Open Chrome. Page loads. Div reads "Waiting for magic."

The state isn't kept between browser closes--even if the cache is. I'm thinking you can implement something similar to make sure they have to login between browser closes. Should work in all browsers too.

Comment: this might work, I will have to adapt it for express and angularjs, but this seems to be the right idea

Comment: You can also use [TransferSize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60323280/975097) to detect if a page is cached.